# How to display the marked position at the very top when jumping to previous mark in iTerm?

Tags: terminal, command-line, unix, iterm

When you jump to a previous mark in iTerm, the marked position will be displayed in (vertically) the middle of the terminal window.

But instead of displaying it in the middle, I want it to be displayed at the very top line (in one go).
Is there a way to make this possible and how?

environment info:

- macOS High Sierra 10.13.3
- iTerm2 Build 3.2.9
- shell integration enabled